# Which projected coordinate system for whole China?

Tags: coordinate-system, distance, direction, china, shape-area

I want to project data of China. I'm not concerned with trying to preserve areal or directional relationships but preserving distances would be nice.

Does such a coordinate system exist?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend an Azimuthal Equidistant projection for what you are looking for. This type of projection:

> "preserves true scale from a single specified point on the projection
>   to all other points on the map."

The example below I set the central meridian to be near Beijeng, China for perspective.

[image]

Here are additional resources:

[Choosing a projection](http://www.geo.hunter.cuny.edu/~jochen/gtech201/lectures/lec6concepts/map%20coordinate%20systems/how%20to%20choose%20a%20projection.htm)

[Azimuthal equidistant projection, centered on Beijing, China, 39⁰55ʹN, 116⁰23ʹE.](https://www.loc.gov/item/89691352/)

Comment: Thanks! Can you detail on what "equidistant" means in the context of projections? What has the same/equal distance to what?

Comment: I would recommend post a new question so that the GIS community may benefit in viewing the post and all have a chance to provide a response. I'll keep a look out for it, or if you may respond here that it is up I can try to provide the best response I can. Hope that helps.